# UFF58 File reader using R Program

Tags: r

I have a input `uff file` with 'n' no.of channels. I want to read the `UFF file` and also split the values based on each individual channel. Then store the result for each channel in separate file. Each channel always start with '-1' '58' etc., and end with '-1'.

Example `channel_01` from the input UFF file:

```
-1
58
filename
22-Mar-2016 10:16:53
164
MnBrgFr-AC225R/N;50.9683995923 mV/m/s2
0         0    0         0 channel_01         0   0 NONE         0   0
2 1048576         1  0.00000E+00  8.19669930804e-06  0.00000E+00
17    0    0    0 Time                 s
1    0    0    0 MnBrgFr-AC225R/N                m/s2
0    0    0    0 NONE                 NONE
0    0    0    0 NONE                 NONE
392.665124452 392.659048025 392.658404832 392.661676933 392.665882251 392.671989083 
392.67634175 392.673743248 392.672398388 392.669360175 392.665533757 392.66088639 
392.660390546 392.660975268 392.663400693 392.662668621 392.661209156 392.65498538 
392.649463269 392.649580214 392.649259786 392.658580248 392.664715147 392.667051694 
-1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As of now, there is no package in R that can read UFF files. Python package for reading UFF file exists [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyuff). A solution can be to write a script in Python that converts the UFF file data into text data. Check [this](https://github.com/openmodal/pyuff/blob/master/pyuff%20Showcase.ipynb)